# Changing contents in array of character pointers

Tags: c

This seems like it should be easy but i've spent way too much time on it. Hopefully someone can help.

```
char *string_labels[5] = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };

void myFunction(void)
{

    //can print them just like expected
    for(i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", string_labels[i]);
    }

    //how can i change the contents of one of the elements??
    sprintf(string_labels[0], "xxx"); <-crashes

}
```

Comment: so is this declaration the same as const char *string_labels = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" }; ?   I thought if it wasn't declared const it would be changeable?   Can you explain why?  Thanks for helping

Comment: Yes, string literals are effectively const, even if they aren't declared as such. Typically they reside in a read-only segment.

Comment: In C, string literals are sequences of char, but are read only. Unfortunately this leads to a lot of confusion. If you are using GCC try using `-Wwrite-strings`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It crashes because it's in read-only memory. Try

```
char string_labels[][6] = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
sprintf(string_labels[0], "xxx");
```

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you need to use a character array, so that you actually have some runtime-writable space to modify:

```
char string_labels[][20] = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };

void myFunction(void)
{
    /* Printing works like before (could be improved, '5' is nasty). */
    for(i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", string_labels[i]);
    }

    /* Now, modifying works too (could be improved, use snprintf() for instance. */
    sprintf(string_labels[0], "xxx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`string_labels` is an array of char pointers pointing to string literals. Since the string literals are read-only, any attempt to modify them leads to undefined behavior.

You can change the declaration of `string_labels` as below to make your `sprintf` work:

```
char string_labels[][6] = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
```

Answer (score 0):

Each of `string_labels[i]` points to a string literal, and attempting to modify the contents of a string literal invokes undefined behavior.

You'll need to declare `string_labels` as an array of arrays of `char`, rather than as an array of pointers to `char`:

```
#define MAX_LABEL_LEN ... // however big the label can get + 0 terminator

char string_labels[][MAX_LABEL_LEN]={"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
```

This declares a 5-element array (size taken from the number of initializers) of `MAX_LABEL_LEN` arrays of `char`.  Now you can write to the contents of `string_labels[i]`.